# Redirect PHP page

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect my page to save.php when i click save button and redirect my page to next.php when I click next button.

```
<form name="crtext" method="post" action="o_crt_ext.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
<input type="submit" name="next" value="next" />
</form>
```

**o_crt_ext.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']));
{
header("location:save.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['next']));
{
header("location:next.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `exit` after you send a location header or you may get unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 6):

remove the semicolons on the if statements

**o_crt_ext.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
  header("location:save.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['next']))
{
  header("location:next.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah, how could I miss those :) +1

Comment: that's why you don't put braces on a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to send any information if the user click on the Next-button? Of not: here you go.

```
 <form name="crtext" method="post" action="o_crt_ext.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
 <input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='next.php'" value="next" />
 </form>
```